# Sharepoint credentials for scheduled refresh

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi

We are using a Sharepoint folder as a source for one of our Power BI reports. We have only used RDBMS sources till now. Using sharepoint there does not seem to be a way to schedule the refresh without using personal organizational account. We do not want to use a person's account when this gets deployed to production. I wasn't able to find any resources online indicating this can be done in any other way.

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this either through some Azure Managed Identity or any other workaround. Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: We checked from our end and there is no option or work around available to schedule  a refresh with out organizational account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We checked from our end and there is no option or work around available to schedule a refresh with out. However you can create a user voice from the below [link](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/)